# Xamarin Forms Android Leave FullScreen Video

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using XamarinMediaManager with VideoView to show video stream. Under Android missed functionality to watch content in full screen mode. I have add custom button to play video in full screen, but could not find way how to leave this mode. TapGestureRecognizer not worked under VideoView

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:mm="clr-namespace:MediaManager.Forms;assembly=MediaManager.Forms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"             
             x:Class="HlsViewer.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HlsViewer.ViewModels"
             Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing"   
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightTextColor">#999999</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentView>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="mmVideoView"  />
            <Button BackgroundColor="Blue" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,100,25" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

ContentPage on Appearing event:

```
private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                mmVideoView.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    Command = new Command(() => {
                        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("1", "s", "OK");
                    }),
                    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
                });

                var item = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.CreateMediaItem("http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8");
                item.MediaType = MediaManager.Library.MediaType.Hls;
                await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(item);
            });
        }
```

Using last version 0.8.11.

Is exist any way to handle leave full screen mode?

Or maybe use other package with embedded functionality?

Comment: If you're viewing in full screen, isn't there a built in platform specific way to leave full screen without having to do anything?

Comment: I have add custom button over VideoView control to put video on full screen and then hide this button when we on full screen. I need to handle tap event on VideoView to show this custom button every time when we tap. This functionality should work in the same way as existed menu on video player